# How to download ICS (iCal) file perioticly without too much duplicate?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cron, calendar, icalendar

I found out, that I can enable a URL to download Google Calendar events using ISC. I got a url like this `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/xxx@gmail.com/private-xxx/basic.ics`.

This url gives me **all** events since the calendar was created. Is there a way to limit it to events that are today or newer? I don't care to update the old ones...